# When comparing CNN architectures, should I use the same learning rate?

Tags: neural-networks, convolution

I am doing a report that compares the performance of ResNet50, VGG16 and EfficientNetB0 on a certain multi-class classification problem. Should I use the same learning rate for each of them or should it vary based on the CNN architecture's size?